# Use HTTP POST to send file to IIS 7.5 virtual directory

Tags: file, http, post, iis-7.5

Is it possible to allow HTTP clients to USE HTTP POST (with Content-Type: multipart/form-data) to upload image files to an IIS 7.5 virtual directory without writing server-side code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Without server-side code, that is not possible. If HTTP POST is a requirement, you need to write code. Otherwise, configure an FTP site on your IIS installation.

If you really need HTTP, consider WebDav:

http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/webdav-iis.html

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis/

Comment: I had wrestled with WebDav for a while before posting the question. I'm having trouble getting WebDav to respond with anything other than 401 and 405 errors. Unfortunately, the client that I am using is Flex, which is limited to GET and POST.

Answer (score 3):

If you enable public write access in IIS with [WebDAV](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/350/installing-and-configuring-webdav-on-iis/), you can upload files using HTTP PUT requests.

[More info](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/360/what39s-new-for-webdav-and-iis/).

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of different *WAYS* you can handle this on the server side ... but all of them involve writing some kind of "code".

SUGGESTION:
Maybe a little asp.net script might be the ticket?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx