# 405 Error $http post json file to a folder using IIS

Tags: angularjs, json, http, post, file-upload

**My Code looks like**

```js
     var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

     myApp.directive('fileModel', ['$parse',
       function($parse) {
         return {
           restrict: 'A',
           link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
             var model = $parse(attrs.fileModel);
             var modelSetter = model.assign;

             element.bind('change', function() {
               scope.$apply(function() {
                 modelSetter(scope, element[0].files[0]);
               });
             });
           }
         };
       }
     ]);

     myApp.service('fileUpload', ['$http',
       function($http) {
         this.uploadFileToUrl = function(file, uploadUrl) {
           var fd = new FormData();
           fd.append('file', file);

           $http.post(uploadUrl, fd, {
             transformRequest: angular.identity,
             headers: {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json'
             }
           })

           .success(function() {})

           .error(function() {});
         }
       }
     ]);

     myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', 'fileUpload',
       function($scope, fileUpload) {
         $scope.uploadFile = function() {
           var file = $scope.myFile;

           console.log('file is ');
           console.dir(file);

           var uploadUrl = "http://localhost:22729/Data/";
           fileUpload.uploadFileToUrl(file, uploadUrl);
         };
       }
     ]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.18/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

  <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <input type="file" file-model="myFile" />
    <button ng-click="uploadFile()">upload me</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Note that I have tried all the alternatives that are available.
[image: ErrorImage]

**The web.config looks like this**

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
  </staticContent>

  <httpProtocol>
    <customHeaders>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
      <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
    </customHeaders>
  </httpProtocol>
```

I tried plenty of alternative options and still facing this problem.

**Also I would like to know how other file types are to be uploaded.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks as if it may be running the default document module via the static file handler. That would be an automatic 405 if so.

Are you expecting this upload to run your server code to capture the upload and save it on the server? If so, you'll have to rearrange the modules and the static file handler and try to get default document module out of the way

Comment: I want the file to get uploaded in the local folder only

Comment: I'll reference another thread that ended up with the same answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8232033/use-http-post-to-send-file-to-iis-7-5-virtual-directory There has to be some form of code on the server side to catch the request and copy the file from the request body to the desired location.